# SmoothState and Wordpress. What function to call on callback for players and Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-visualization

I think this is a purely technical question, even though I speak of using wordpress in this case and specific plugin and shortcode.

I use in my Wordpress [SmoothState.js](https://github.com/weblinc/jquery.smoothState.js). Everything works fine, except for two things:

1 - "Visualizer" or "Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer" plugin for wordpress that use Google Charts. I can not find a function to call on the "callback".

2 - same thing when in use MediaElement Wordpress for native audio player with playlist with native shortcode and shortcode too. Appear on the first page, but then I do not know what to call on the callback to redisplay the players.

How to solve?

Maybe I can post something more technical, but if I had known where to look for the function to be called I would not have posted this question here.

Comment: Maybe no one has done this before? If so, it will be difficult to help without seeing the [relevant code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What do you mean by `function to call on the "callback"`?

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo. The code of my site is available here: http://ginolon.altervista.org

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using the `isFired` control for jQuery as explained in the blog post [SmoothState.js & WordPress](http://www.parsonsprojects.co.uk/smoothstate-wordpress/) <sub><sup>(h/t: this [Github issue](https://github.com/weblinc/jquery.smoothState.js/issues/64#issuecomment-53592370))</sup></sub>.

In the comments of that post, the author says:

> Yes that is what I would do go into the plugin find the registered scripts then de-register and register them back a bit of a pain but at the moment I dont think there is another way of doing this.
>
> An ideal solution would be to write something that finds all the registered scripts and loads them all in without duplicating them.

What I did to make your **#2** work is to enqueue MediaElement when I'm enqueuing SmoothState:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
```

WP only enqueues it when there's a media shortcode on the page. If we start from another page without it, the script is not enqueued when SS loads a page that contains the media element.

A calendar plugin of mine had your same issue **#1**, beside enqueueing the scripts on my SS, I had to start up the main function (declared as global) on the callback, see below. Observations:

- it will depend on each plugin;
- I'm not sure if it's good idea be calling this global function at each callback;
- if you don't want to [hack the plugins JS files](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/tags/0.6.2.1/igsv-datatables.js), maybe deregistering/dequeuing their JS files and enqueuing your own could work;
- as you're manipulating other plugins behaviors, you should [create a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pageSize=50) to handle your SmoothState, working from `functions.php` won't cut the deal.

**FullCalendar plugin** (simplified):

```
var editor_data = new Function();

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    editor_data = function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ options });
    }
    editor_data();
});
```

**SmoothState plugin** (simplified):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $body = $('html, body'),
    content = $('#page').smoothState({
        onEnd : {
            duration: 0, // Duration of the animations, if any.
            render: function (url, $container, $content) {
                $container.html($content);
                $(document).ready();
                $(window).trigger('load');
            }
        },
        callback: function(url, $container, $content) {
            editor_data();
        }
    }).data('smoothState');
});

(function($, undefined) {
    var isFired = false;
    var oldReady = jQuery.fn.ready;
    $(function() {
        isFired = true;
        $(document).ready();
    });
    jQuery.fn.ready = function(fn) {
        if(fn === undefined) {
            $(document).trigger('_is_ready');
            return;
        }
        if(isFired) {
            window.setTimeout(fn, 1);
        }
        $(document).bind('_is_ready', fn);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo for your answer. But for the #1 problem the problem is still there. because even if I enqueue the script from functions.php or directly in the head by <script> tag, the result does not change. I use the tag [playlist] in the posts and widgets and on the home of my website everything works. Then, when (through SmoothState) I visit the site, the subsequent pages no longer display the player. Nothing appears. I think it's for the same reason of the problem # 2, that is the call some function on callback, but my question is: what function to call?

Comment: For the problem #1 I know how to do. What I don't know is what to call on callback for plugin "Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer" (that use Google Chart, because the spreadsheet works).